# Regex is failing for few URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url

I am having a Regex as `/url\s*\((?!['("]?(?:data):)['"]?([^')"\)]*)['"]?([\)]|$)/gi`
where we are using it to parse style tag to get URL(ex.backgroundImage). It fails for URL such as

1] `background-image: url(\2f content\2f dam\2f dx\2fus\2f en\2f error-pages\2f 404-1440x612_edge2.jpg\2fjcr%3acontent\2frenditions\2f cq5dam.tablet_1400.1400.595.jpg); background-position: 50% 50%;`

should be => `url(\2f content\2f dam\2f dx\2fus\2f en\2f error-pages\2f 404-1440x612_edge2.jpg\2fjcr%3acontent\2frenditions\2f cq5dam.tablet_1400.1400.595.jpg)`

2] background-image: `url("https://www.investopedia.com/thmb/m3EwtlYfbUhlr9e34AofFj9wok8=/1300x0/filters:contrast(10):brightness(-10):no_upscale()/TopTerms-2bdc464d466944deb41fc07379407600.jpeg")`

should be  => `url("https://www.investopedia.com/thmb/m3EwtlYfbUhlr9e34AofFj9wok8=/1300x0/filters:contrast(10):brightness(-10):no_upscale()/TopTerms-2bdc464d466944deb41fc07379407600.jpeg")`

It fails at contrast(10): as it consider contrast(10) closing bracket as end of URL.

3] `background-image:url('https://cdn.comcast.com/-/media/Images/www_xfinity_com/TV/X1/09072021 Refresh/10X1HeroDesktop.png?rev=d04c61c0-3658-457d-8260-74ef6694c0ed&mw=1280&mh=600&hash=6A1C4FEC8499EE38864BA31D24B9E42220D8C7EB')" background-size: cover;`

should be => `url('https://cdn.comcast.com/-/media/Images/www_xfinity_com/TV/X1/09072021 Refresh/10X1HeroDesktop.png?rev=d04c61c0-3658-457d-8260-74ef6694c0ed&mw=1280&mh=600&hash=6A1C4FEC8499EE38864BA31D24B9E42220D8C7EB')`

4] `style="position:absolute; background:transparent url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat 0 0"`

should be => `url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=)`

Comment: Try `url\s*\("?((?!['("]?data:)\S+?\.jpe?g)"?\)` https://regex101.com/r/JXbzpi/1/

Comment: What should the result be for both examples?

Comment: How many matches do you expect for the string with tje `\2f` in it?

Comment: Thanks, regex you gave works for investopedia example. I have edited post and added few more examples, also have mentioned what is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an alternation `|` to get the different formats.

```
url\s*\((?:data:image\S+|(['"]).*?\1|[^()]*)\)
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `url\s*\(` Match url, optional whitespace chars an `(`
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `data:image\S+` Match data:image and 1+ non whiteapace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `(['"]).*?\1` Match from opening quote to closing quote
  - `|` Or
  - `[^()]*` Match 0+ times any char except parenthesis
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L8zL8w/1)